# How save gstreamer images directly into a PyQt5 vairiable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, gstreamer

I have a gstreamer pipeline that capture an image and saves it in a folder on a specific location

```
gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc num-buffers=1 sensor_id=0 ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=4608, height=2592, framerate=14/1, format=NV12' ! nvjpegenc ! filesink location=myImage.jpg
```

would it be possible to have the image captured by the gstreamer pipeline be directly stored into a python variable which i can then used in pyqt for displaying. I would like to skip the step of having the gstreamer saving it into file, then i have to open that file again in pyqt.

Here is a stripped down of the pyQt code where i want to use the jpg file:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import sys

#Something along the lines of 
#imageData = getImageFromGstreamer("gst-launch-1.0....")

class Menu(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Title")
        
        self.central_widget = QWidget()               
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)    
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        
        label = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('logo.png') # QPixmap(imageData)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(), pixmap.height())
        
        lay.addWidget(label)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Does PyQt5 have gstreamer libraries that i can use to directly grab the image that came from the gstreamer?

Answer (score 1):

DrakeJest

Utilize [Appsink](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GstApp-1.0/classes/AppSink.html#GstApp.AppSink) within your pipeline to efficiently transmit data buffers to your program. Take note on the ["new-sample"](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GstApp-1.0/classes/AppSink.html#GstApp.AppSink.signals.new_sample) and ["pull-sample"](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GstApp-1.0/classes/AppSink.html#GstApp.AppSink.signals.pull_sample) signals usage. First, you will want to add a handler on the "new-sample" signal, for that you will use the [.connect](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.connect) method from the GObject of the Appsink object you retrieved from your pipeline. Now, from that handler prepare your image: pull a sample by emitting with [.emit](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html#GObject-2.0/classes/Object.html#GObject.Object.emit) the "pull-sample" signal; once you have the sample, you can get the buffer from it and from the buffer you can get the image. Into the handler implement a callback to forward the images. From the callback encapsulate your image from buffer's raw image as a QImage and seamlessly integrate it into the Pixmap. This is how you can incorporate the images from your pipeline onto your application.

```py
from typing import Any
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage, QColor
import sys

import gi
import numpy as np

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib


appsink_pipeline_str = "videotestsrc is-live=true ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=360,format=BGRx ! appsink name=appsink emit-signals=true async=false"

# 4 channels for BGRx format
channels = 4

class GStreamerPipeline:
    def __init__(self, pipeline_str) -> None:
        Gst.init(None)

        self.pipeline = None
        self.pipeline_str = pipeline_str

        self._create_pipeline()

    def _create_pipeline(self):
        try:
            self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(self.pipeline_str)
        except GLib.GError:
            print("Unable to create the pipeline")

    def start_pipeline(self):
        ret = self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
        if Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE == ret:
            print("Unable to start the pipeline")

        state, _, _ = self.pipeline.get_state(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE)
        print ("state -> %s ", state)
        if Gst.StateChangeReturn.SUCCESS != state:
            print("Unable to set the pipeline state to playing")
    
    def stop_pipeline(self):
        ret = self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        if Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE == ret:
            print("Unable to stop the pipeline")


class GStreamerImages:
    def __init__(self, pipeline, callback) -> None:
        self.pipeline = pipeline
        self.appsink = None
        self.callback = callback
        self.buffer_memory_obj = None
        self.buffer_minfo = None

        self.create_buffer_callback()

    def create_buffer_callback(self):
        self.appsink = self.pipeline.pipeline.get_by_name("appsink")
        self.appsink.connect("new-sample", self.new_buffer_callback, self.appsink)

    def new_buffer_callback(self, appsink, data):
        sample = appsink.emit("pull-sample")

        height, width, stride, raw_buffer = self.retrieve_image_from_buffer(sample)
        self.callback( height, width, stride, raw_buffer)

    def retrieve_image_from_buffer(self, sample):
        buffer = sample.get_buffer()
        caps = sample.get_caps()

        # Map the buffer
        self.buffer_memory_obj = buffer.get_all_memory()
        ret, self.buffer_minfo = self.buffer_map(self.buffer_memory_obj, Gst.MapFlags.READ)
        if ret is not True:
            print("Unable to map the buffer")
            return None

        # Retrieve the buffer's image shape
        width = caps.get_structure(0).get_value("width")
        height = caps.get_structure(0).get_value("height")
        format = caps.get_structure(0).get_value("format")

        raw_buffer = self.buffer_minfo.data

        stride = channels * width

        return height, width, stride, raw_buffer

    def buffer_map(self, buffer_memory_obj, map_flags):
        ret, buffer_minfo = buffer_memory_obj.map(map_flags)

        return ret, buffer_minfo

    def _buffer_unmap(self, buffer_memory_obj, buffer_minfo):
        buffer_memory_obj.unmap(buffer_minfo)

    def __del__(self):
        self._buffer_unmap(self.buffer_memory_obj, self.buffer_minfo)


class CbQtOnGStreamerImages:
    def __init__(self, label) -> None:
        self.label = label

        self.qt_image=None
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_image)
        self.timer.start(10)

    def __call__(self, height, width, stride, raw_buffer) -> Any:
        self.qt_image = QImage(raw_buffer, width, height,  stride, QImage.Format_RGB32)
        self.update_image()

    def update_image(self):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(self.qt_image))

class Menu(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Title")

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.lay = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)

        # GStreamer setup
        self.gst_pipeline = GStreamerPipeline(appsink_pipeline_str)

        self.gst_pipeline.start_pipeline()

        # Bind stuff here. Pass the Qt object that requires the GStreamer images feed
        self.callback = CbQtOnGStreamerImages(self.label)

        self.gst_images = GStreamerImages(self.gst_pipeline, self.callback)

        self.lay.addWidget(self.label)

        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Menu()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: So i was able to solve it in a different way, i still used gstreamer appsinks. but utilized openCV to capture the image. What would be the benifits of doing it this way instead of openCV.read() function?